# How to make a list of lists using a str

Tags: python, list

I have a list

```
['r', 'o', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'o']`
```

and wish to make it

```
[['r','o'], ['c', 'o'], ['c', 'o']]
```

how would I do this?
moreover, I need to make the new list grouped to whatever "n" is
in the above example, n is 2
if n is 3, the result should be:
[['r', 'o', 'c']['o','c','o']]

Answer (score 7):

The [`itertools` recipes](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) have a general-purpose function that does exactly what you're looking for with any kind of iterator, called `grouper`:

```
>>> values = ['r', 'o', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'o']
>>> groups = grouper(values, 3)
```

However, this returns you an iterator. If you want a list, you have to ask for one explicitly:

```
>>> groups = list(grouper(values, 3))
>>> print(groups)
[('r', 'o', 'c'), ('o', 'c', 'o')]
```

Also, note that this gives you a list of *tuples*, not a list of *lists*. Most likely this doesn't actually matter to you. But if it does, you'll have to convert them:

```
>>> list_groups = [list(group) for group in grouper(values, 3)]
>>> print(list_groups)
[['r', 'o', 'c'], ['o', 'c', 'o']]
```

---

If you install [`more_itertools`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools) off PyPI, you can just `from more_itertools import grouper`. Otherwise, you'll have to copy and paste from the recipes into your code.

But either way, it's worth understanding how `grouper` works:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

First, it creates an iterator out of your iterable. (This is something that keeps track of its current position and returns values one by one as you call `next` on it, until you've reached the end.) Then it makes `n` references to that iterator. This is the tricky bit—you don't want `n` separate iterators to the same list, you want `n` references to the *same* iterator, so if you grab the `next` value out of the first iterator, they *all* move forward. That's why it does the funny `[iter(iterable)] * n` bit. Then it just `zip`s the iterators together. So, the first pass through the `zip` calls `next` on the first iterator, then the second, then the third; the second pass through the `zip` again calls `next` on the first iterator, then the second, then the third; and so on.

The reason it uses `zip_longest` instead of just `zip` (or, in Python 2.x, `izip_longest` vs. `izip`) is so `list(grouper(['r', 'o', 'c', 'o'], 3))` will give you `[('r', 'o', 'c'), ('o', None, None)]` instead of just `[('r', 'o', 'c')]`. If that's not what you want, it's trivial to just use the other function instead.

For further explanation, see [this blog post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-grouper-works.html).

Comment: This is a more comprehensive version of my answer (which I deleted). +1, this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @arshajii: But your answer was more concise, which is why I upvoted it… I guess we don't really need two versions of the same thing, but I liked yours.

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
>>> a = ['r', 'o', 'c', 'o', 'c', 'o']
>>> zip(*[iter(a)]*2)
[('r', 'o'), ('c', 'o'), ('c', 'o')]

>>> zip(*[iter(a)]*3)
[('r', 'o', 'c'), ('o', 'c', 'o')]
```

You can change the `2 and 3` to the number you want.

Comment: this is good, but other solutions are more readable imo

Comment: A potential problem here is that elements will start getting left out if the list can't be evenly partitioned. Try this with `4`, for example.

Comment: @arshajii: That may or may not be what you want, of course. Usually it isn't, in which case you need to use `zip_longest` (and optionally pass a `fillvalue`).

Comment: By the way, this is effectively equivalent to the `grouper` recipe; the only reason it's less readable is that it isn't wrapped up in a function (with a nice name for the function and params, and possibly comments). And, as I said in my answer, it really is worth being able to understand why this answer works.

Comment: Yes, it just uses `zip()` instead of `zip_longest()`, should have used that though. Your answer was perfect @abarnert. :)

Comment: @SukritKalra: Well, maybe 70% of the time you want `zip_longest`, 25% of the time you want `zip`, so really, it's worth having (and explaining) both answers…

Answer (score 0):

```
[l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
```